# Quick disconnects - cheap alternatives?

Tags: equipment

I'm looking to get some 1/2" NPT & barbed quick-disconnect fittings for my little brewery, making it easier to break down and clean, as well as give me some flexibility in what I'm sending where.

I was expecting to find the fittings in brass for under $5 in a bunch of places... I see garden hose quick disconnect fittings for that all over the place, but I was surprised and frustrated to find the cheapest ones for like $12 once I went away from the garden hoses.  Granted, there's a smaller market, but that's a pretty big difference in price for what is ultimately the same thing.

I have approximately 12 points I'd like to put in quick-disconnects.  I don't want to spend $200+.

Has anyone found alternatives to this, or perhaps some place where I can get these parts cheap?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [Brewer's Hardware](http://www.brewershardware.com/cam_and_groove_fittings/) or [Bargin Fitting's](http://www.bargainfittings.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=51) selection of quick connects.

They've got [stainless camlocks](http://www.bargainfittings.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=51_54&product_id=135) for about $6 each, which seem to be very popular among home brewers:

[image] [image]

Bargian Fittings also has [chrome plated brass quick connects](http://www.bargainfittings.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=51_55) for $8 and $5:

[image]

Actually, if you don't mind aluminum, [these camlocks](http://store.proflowdynamics.com/modules/store/-Aluminum_C69.cfm) are less than $3 each.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... still considerably more expensive than the garden hose brass disconnects, but also a manageable expense.  I'd seen the camlock ones advertized, but I'd assumed they would be much more expensive.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I just edited my answer with another link for you - a friend uses these aluminum camlocks, and they're dirt cheap.

Comment: Your link does not seem to go where I would expect it to.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Whoooooops!  I was showing someone else my home bar and pasted the wrong link :)  That'll teach me to be lazy and not click my links before posting.  It has been fixed.

Comment: I ordered some.  Still more expensive than I think they should be but 1) they seem to be quality stuff, 2) they'll do the job, and 3) they look cool.

Answer (score 1):

For cheap disconnects, go with cam locks.  Tri-clamp is easier to clean, but a bit more expensive.  Garden hose disconnects are generally too low in quality to consider.

I only know about garden hose disconnect issues because, well, I water a garden daily.  If I can't keep my garden hose from leaking, I wouldn't want to recommend them for beer.

Hopefully cam locks are within your budget.  If not, I'd actually consider leaning more towards hose clamps than garden hose disconnects.

Answer (score 0):

I sell directly to homebrewers and commercial brewers alike.  You can find most of the quick disconnect, tri-clamp fittings online here:  https://sanitaryfittings.us/brewery-fittings

I'm a homebrewer myself and like to help out others dedicated to the craft.  You can save 10% off your first order with us by using coupon code **"brewer10".**

Please let me know if I can be of any assistance.

Comment: This and your other answers with your store's link sound very much like spam. If you want to answer the question, please provide more information than just a link to a store.

Comment: The OP asks for somewhere where he can find these parts cheap, the answer contains a 10% discount code, and links to a site that sells brewery fittings. Also, the poster is upfront that it is their site. Due to the nature of the question and the upfront nature of the answer, I consider this Ham; not Spam. Equally, it is not a great answer so I imagine it will not get many upvotes.

Comment: Hi, Robert. SPAM was not my intention on this post at all.  I'm happy to see that "Mr Road" agrees.  To be more specific with my answer to the  OP, we sell both Male/Female NPT x Tri-Clamp connections in both 304 & 316 stainless.  I'd post a link specifically to these parts for sale but that appears to raise some eyebrows here.  Again, please let me know if I can be of assistance with your homebrew fittings.